# Checking String for illegal characters using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to check a for any illegal character using the following regular expression in PHP.  Essentially, I want to allow only alphanumeric and underscore (_).  Unfortunately the follow piece of code does not seem to work properly.  It should return true if there is any illegal character in the string $username.  However, it still allows any character in the string.  Any idea what is wrong with the regular expression?

```
if ( !preg_match("/^[-a-z0-9_]/i", $username) )
{
    return true;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code checks to see if the first character is not valid.  To check to see if *any* invalid characters exist, negate your character class rather than the function return and remove the anchor:

```
if ( preg_match("/[^-a-z0-9_]/i", $username) )
{
    return true;
}
```

You could also, of course, shorten it to `/[^-\w]/` ("word" characters are letters, numbers, and the underscore), or even just `/\W/` if you don't want to allow dashes.

Comment: This solution is better than the ones matching entire strings, since preg_match can return true as soon as it encounters a non-allowed character. It won't matter much on something as short as a username, though.

Answer (score 2):

If `$username` only has alphanumeric and underscore it will return TRUE

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9_]+$/i", $username) )
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression matches only 1 character.  Try **/^[-a-z0-9_]+$/i** the '+' matches more then 1 character and the '$' is the end of line anchor

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor it at the end too, instead of just checking the first character. Try `"/^[-a-z0-9_]*$/i"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have no repeater for one. You need a repeater such as +. As far as I can see without executing it, you check start of line and one character matching a-zA-Z0-9 and _ but nothing following that first character.